# Nuxt external js don't load after change page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a **Nuxt App**, but I encounter problem.

When I run the app, the first render load my external **javascript** works fine.
Here comes the **ERROR/MALFUNCTION** when I change page and comeback to that page - the **javascript** doesn't load.

I put my external **javascript** to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
...
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js', body: true, defer: ''},
      { src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', body: true, defer: ''},
      { src: '/js/owl.carousel.js', body: true, defer: ''},
      { src: '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', body: true, defer: ''},
      { src: '/js/main.js', body: true, defer: ''},
    ],
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
  },
...
}
```

How can I render my external **javascript** that render every load or page call?
I want my external **javascript** to render all the way.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by _"when I change page and comeback to that page"_? Are you navigating by clicking links? Typing URLs directly into your browser? Trying to reload the current page?

Comment: yes I navigate trough pages by clicking its link I'm using `this.$router.push()` method to navigate links and when I come back to the page where my external **javascript** has a purpose it doesn't render the content that I wrote. But when in the first load it shows

Comment: Again, what do you mean by _"when I **come back** to the page"_? It sounds like you may need to use some [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) to execute code before rendering specific pages

Comment: e.g. when I start the app the page load **HOME PAGE**. then I click **ABOUT PAGE**. then when I click AGAIN **HOME PAGE** my javascript doesn't work anymore. That what I meant by ***"when I come back to the page"***

Comment: secondly I don't want to use middleware because I want to create a static website generated by nuxt

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The routing middleware runs client-side after routing but before rendering your page. At least, that's what the documentation says ~ _"In SPA mode, middlewares will be called client-side on the first request and when navigating to further routes"_

Comment: I'm using universal method not SPA. Is client-side middleware is applicable to nuxt universal app

Comment: I don't think you can create a static website in universal mode but that's beside the point. Using the `middleware` property in your page will execute that middleware when you render that page

Comment: how can I access `head()` function on my middleware?

Comment: Which particular external js that you are loading is not present on redirect? If it's what you have in `main.js' then maybe that should be in a plugin.

Comment: I am talking about NUXT, I don't have that main.js thing. I have my external JS in my static file then I put it to **nuxt.config.js** `head`. When I load my app for the first time the external JS works fine but then when I navigate trough routes using `this.$router.push()` the external JS doesn't work.

Comment: its a bad idea to use scripts like jquery and related things in nuxt project. It only adds problems and create hard to maintain websites

Comment: @Aldarund is there any other way on how to solved this error, I need the owl carousel to my application. I tried to import owl carousel on my NUXT app by using its library `npm i -s vue-owl-carousel` but when the initial load the application got error 

> window is not defined.

but when I tried to go to other pages it work and come back it also work

Comment: @codeformoney your question about window not defined is covered in nuxt faq https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined

Comment: where is my `.vue` file and where am I going to put it before `export default`? or `mounted`?